# linux ps command to list number of running processes in super user root

Tags: linux, terminal, ps

I am looking for. a command that I can list the number of running processes by superuser root and pipe it to wc -l

i already did **ps -ef | grep ^$USER wc -l** however that only shows for the current user

Answer (score 0):

To display all root processes use:

```
sudo ps -U root -u root -o comm= | wc -l
```

Where:

- `-U` : select real user ID
- `-u` : select effective user ID
- `-o comm=` : select no columns, so the header line will not be output.

Comment: Why to use sudo here ?  I tkink all users can run this command line and get the same result.

Comment: @ctac_: This will show processes that are otherwise omitted.

Comment: You are certainly right but what sort of process can be omitted ?